# ASP.Net MVC 3 Ajax query not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, entity-framework-4

I have a very simple ajax call to refresh some data on my webpage, but it doesn't seem to fire correctly. The data that the call brings back is the same everytime even if the underlying data changes.
The ajax call looks like this:

```
function RefreshContent() {
        //create the link
        var link = "/Address/ListByAjax/" + $('#Id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: link,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#Address").html(data);
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert('an error occured: ' + error);
            }
        });
    }
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult ListByAjax(int Id)
{
    var list = db.Address.Where(i => i.Person_Id == Id);
    return PartialView("_List", list.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the cache to false in your ajax call - that will force the browser to send the request through to the controller:

```
function RefreshContent() {
        //create the link
        var link = "/Address/ListByAjax/" + $('#Id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: link,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#Address").html(data);
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert('an error occured: ' + error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
`ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); });`

This turns off caching for all ajax calls made by your app.